# Dynamically add to list of items on Razor view using MVC, and ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently making a sales screen on my web application, that has an input box for a product SKU.

I'm trying to add to the sale list using an action, that takes the model with the inputted SKU. The action then searches for the relevant product in the database and adds it the models list.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-check">Scan Product</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddEpc, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

This works, the item gets added, and shown in the list, but as I add more items, the list is emptied, and will only ever contain a single object.

Here is the code for my razor view, iterating over the list of objects:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Inventory</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var p in Model.SaleItems) {
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-8">
                @p.InventoryId
            </td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Inventory", new {id = @p.Id}, null)</td>
        </tr>
     }
</table>
```

All the other fields stay, such as Customer information, within the customer object.

Can anyone provide me with an ideal workaround? I don't have experience with JQuery, or Javascript, and I'm trying to run this solely using ASP, but if it is really necessary, I'll look into learning JQuery to support it.

Comment: You could create another model property of type List<T> and have it bound to a bunch of hidden elements in your form, on post back to server, use that to add back in the previous items to your drop down list plus the new one.

Comment: Can you show your model and controller actions for returning the view and adding the item to the sale items.

Comment: so you use TextBox to search for SKU , if exist you right away add it to a list ??
where do you save this list ? 
because if every time you call your controller and refreshing your page the list will always be empty and only have one item in your List
are you trying to make a shopping cart ?

Comment: @RyanWilson This solution works for me. I now have a List of strings that are passed through using @Html.HiddenFor() helpers, for each stored product code. This then allows me to populate a list of sale items server side. This might be a bit slower than other solutions, but it's working for me, and sales orders tend to be small.

Comment: @Rixium Cool. Glad that is working for you. I would suggest taking some time to learn javascript, JQuery is optional but I like it as it makes doing some of the same things in plain javascript easier.

Comment: Thanks, Appreciate the help, if you most if as a full answer. I'll accept it. Working on Javascript and JQuery asap.